# How to iterate throught fields names in a table and change row values?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder

I got table like that one ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Rjrt.jpg)).

I need to change 0 to 1 and -1 to 0 in each field except first and second.

The problem is that every time i have different number of fields and field name is changed too, but i can use wildcard    "FID_"   to select a field name.

I read some stuff about, should be like that:

```
 def test(field.name):
  fieldList = ListFields(%path%)
  for field in fieldList:
    if (field.name)==0:
      EQ=1
    else:
      EQ=0
    return EQ
```

%path% should be the value taken from model-builder (if that is possilbe).

Comment: If your preference is ModelBuilder, think about Iterators and Model Only Tools like Calculate Value, or if it is Python/ArcPy, then I think you will need to use getValue and setValue.

Comment: Why not just do this in field calculator?  You could use the same snippet in each field and skip modelbuilder all together.

Answer (score 1):

This would be difficult to do in modelbuilder as there is no iterator that iterates over columns. This would be much easier if done in Python, using as @Roy says the field calculator. Below is the required code:

```py
import arcpy
myTable = r"C:\Temp\New_dBASE_Table.dbf"
fields = arcpy.ListFields(myTable)
for f in fields:
    if f.name[:4] == "FID_":
        print "Processing " + f.name
        exp = "change(!" + f.name + "!)"
        # The code assumes if it is not zero then it must be -1
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(myTable, f.name, exp, "PYTHON_9.3", "def change(v):\n  if v == 0:\n    return 1\n  else:\n    return 0")
```